# appengine dashboard is not showing any stat for a couple of hours

Tags: google-app-engine

I am testing out my appengine app and I have not been able to see any stat on the Dashboard for a couple of hours already. There is nothing on the graph. The app has been running for a while (79% of a frontend instance hours) The URIs being called from has been completely blank.

[image]

Comment: Yep, it does that sometimes. Aside from this, make sure you're looking at the correct version of your app if you have multiple versions deployed.

Comment: Wow, encouraging. Yeh, I am looking at the correct version. Thanks tho. ("sometimes == a couple of hours" is not good tho.)

Comment: I've never had your problem...yet, but maybe google-analytics will help you see how much traffic your site is generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced some lags before, but never at that level. Perhaps you could get in touch with the GAE team through a [production issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue).